# SaaS boilerplate vs Webflow Ui kit (SaaS template°

Tags: web-applications, aspnetboilerplate, saas, webflow

I habe been recommended to use a template to speed op the programming but I would like to now the differences of using a webflow UI vs a SaaS boilerplate to build a web application and what the pro and the cons are

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your product and what problem you're trying to solve for your clients, the saas boilerplates are a good starting point to speed up your project also you have full contrôle of customization but if you think that webflow fit your needs now and for the future, you can use it. please check this article for more details: https://dev.to/aminezel/why-you-should-use-saas-boilerplate-starter-kits-to-speed-up-your-app-development-1p4h